# Task created by Process Builder not showing in Activity Timeline until refresh

Tags: lightning, process-builder, activities

I'm struggling with the following problem:
My goal is to create a task for an Opportunity once the Opportunity stage changes, which is set using the sales path. I'm using process builder to create the task, which works fine.

But unfortunately, the activity timeline on the Opportunity record page doesn't show the new task until i click the reload activities button or refresh the page - which is a usability nightmare.
I believe that this behavior might be an order of execution issue.

I'm thankful for any input on how i could solve that issue or maybe avoid that kind of logic in the first place whilst keeping task creation automated.

Comment: I think, you can initiate a flow and after creation refresh this page would might help.

Comment: You might look into visual workflow than process builder

Comment: Thanks guys! Not too familiar with visual workflow so that idea didn't even come to my mind.